# CSS before and after selectors with multiple asterisks and commas

Tags: css, css-selectors

What does this CSS statement do, and how does it work?

```
*,*:before,*:after{box-sizing:inherit}
```

Why is this whole statement not simply `*{box-sizing:inherit}`?

What specifically is the purpose of `*,*` when applied to before?

Why apply the same inherit condition *before* all elements *and* *after* all elements?

What is the purpose of applying `{box-sizing:inherit}` before or after all selected elements?

Why apply it to all elements, and before all elements and after all elements? Why not just apply it to all elements?

What does it all amount to? What does it do?

Comment: `*,*` doesn't have a purpose. `*` does, `*:before` does and `*:after` does; `,` just means "and" in this context.

Comment: sometimes `::before` and `::after` don't work if you don't put `content: "";`

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas they don't work at all unless they have a `content` property declared. Not sometimes, all the time.

Comment: @disinfor yes, Is was a typo error, I know that is not working all the time if there isn't `content`... yes this because I commented to his with this (I have experience with this bug)